# Why isn't the entire Android app moved to the SD card?

Tags: android, sd-card

Is there a resource somewhere that says what pieces of an Android app are moved to the SD card when you click the 'Move to SD card' button? In the Applications screen, my app shows up as being 5.62MB, but when I move to SD card, it shows up as 4.26MB, which is still higher than I prefer.

A significant amount of my app is in autogenerated Java code. Does the program itself get moved to the SD card, or is it only the resources in the res directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it seems that only the resources are moved to the external memory, please see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) more details.

Comment: That's interesting... only the APK is moved, which would account for the difference in space.